# Most efficient algorithm to find if a path exists

Tags: c++, algorithm, path-finding

I'm looking for an algorithm that tells me whether a path between point A and point B exists.
I don't need to know what the path actually is, I just need to know if it exists or not, and execution time is key. The base grid had either empty fields or walls, just those two.
Could you guys suggest something?

EDIT: I thought I would clarify. What I have is a basic grid like this:

```
O O O X O
O O O X X
O O O X O
O O X X O
O O O X O
```

where O - empty space, X - wall, starting point A(0, 0) and end B(4, 4). What I'm trying to do is to check how many times I can remove a single wall for the path to exist, end point to be reachable.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reachability

Comment: thanks for those wiki links, but are those really the fastest in terms of determining if a path exists or not?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search will be the most efficient if the grid is huge, but the path is short.

Comment: Are A and B points given as queries to check on?

Comment: Would Breadth-first search be faster than A* when trying to check if a path exist? The grid I'm doing this on is 100x100 cells.

Comment: @nice_dev what exactly do you mean by queries? What I have is for example starting point A(1, 1) and B(15,21), which is the end node.

Comment: In the worst case, A* is just a slow BFS. Note that any time the answer is "not reachable" is a worst case for A*. So A* will only be faster on average if the answer is "reachable".

Comment: @user3386109 based on what I'm doing, the answer is going to be "not reachable" most of the time.

Comment: Well, may I suggest you update your question to explain what exactly you are doing?  Perhaps you are iteratively updating a grid to search for solutions, in which case a full BFS probably isn't a good solution.  We can only speculate, because you have already decided what you need and asked about that..  Whereas maybe you're asking the wrong question.

Comment: @tomnookey Ok, in that case I would expect A* to be significantly slower than BFS. That's because it's going explore every reachable point, and at each point it has to compute the heuristic and add the point to a priority queue: O(logn) insertion and removal. BFS will also explore every reachable point, but there's no heuristic to calculate, and only a simple queue: O(1) insertion/removal.

Comment: Regarding paddy's comment. If you intend to remove walls until the destination is reachable, then you'll want to keep track of all reachable points on the grid, and then start an incremental BFS from the newly opened grid point (assuming it's next to a reachable point).

Comment: @paddy I have updated my question as you advised, I hope I explained it better this time.

Comment: Your question is now contradictory: which is true? *"I just need to know if it exists or not"*, or *"how many times I can remove a single wall for the path to exist"*?. The first is a boolean, the second is a number...

Comment: An algorithm such as Union/Find for disjoint sets might also be useful in this case, if you're only interested in _reachability_ by removing wall segments.  You simply add the starting point and the ending point, and add any connected segments to your sets.  However, it won't easily help you find the _optimal_ solution.  For that, you might want to try something like Dijkstra's algorithm, where you mark walls with a cost of 1 and empty cells with a cost of 0.  You will then find the shortest number of walls to traverse (i.e. remove) to get to your end result.

Comment: @trincot I was trying to find the best algorithm for the boolean to then remove each one of the walls in a loop and check whether a path exists or not. Since paddy asked me to elaborate more on my problem, I decided to present the entire thing to you guys, and not just the bit I was trying to find out about.

Comment: thanks so much @paddy, I'll look into all the things you suggested and try to figure out the solution to this. Really appreciate your input.

Comment: Well yeah, and it's good that you elaborated, because you were presenting a [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/200806), assuming you needed fast traversal because you assumed you'd need to do it thousands of times to guess the solution.  Look into Dijkstra, or even just A*.  Both are cost-based BFS traversals.  If you incorporate walls as a cost element, you'll figure out the minimum number of walls to remove.  And with back-tracking, you'll know _which_ walls they are.  You get all this with essentially a single BFS.

Comment: You need to perform two breadth-first searches, one from A and one from B. If A and B are connected, then the question is moot, no walls need to be removed. Otherwise, any wall that's reachable from both A and B can be removed to connect A and B.

Comment: Thanks for everything guys, I've used two breadth-first searches just like @user3386109 suggested and it works exactly how I wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have only 2 points `A` and `B` to check for in your 2D grid, you can adopt [`depth first search`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) or [`breadth first search`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) to check if the path exists.

---

If you are given the grid and several pairs of points to check against in the form of queries, you can adopt the below approach:

- We iterate over the 2D grid cell by cell only on non visited empty cells.
- We will use depth first search(or breadth first search), whichever you prefer to mark these cells.
- Marking process includes moving over empty cells and marking them with a value, say a number. All connected empty cells form an island.
- This way, if any 2 pair of points belong to the same island, a path exists between them and if they don't belong to the same island, no route exists.

You can refer to below pictures for better visualization. Here, black cells are walls and colored cells are islands meaning cells marked with some value who belong to the same connected component.

[image]
[image]

- In the above algorithm, the time complexity to mark every cell with a color or a number will be `O(m * n)` where `m` and `n` are the no. of rows and columns, as we visit every cell only once during our DFS or BFS.
- Time complexity to answer every query for any 2 pair of points will be `O(1)`.

Comment: It could probably improve the performance to apply a heuristic for the next cell to choose in the DFS, similar to A*

Comment: @Justin Interesting, can you give an example of a heuristic for the next cell to choose?

Comment: See amit's answer. "Closest to destination" is a decent heuristic, but I'm not familiar enough with A* to know good heuristics.

Answer (score 1):

[A*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm) and its variants are often used for this kind of problems.

A* search algorithm does informed decision on which cells should be explored next, before exploring it, and by doing this it can search faster by leaving "not interesting" nodes (cells) unexplored.

Since you do not care much about *optimality*, you can also utilize [bounded relaxation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm#Bounded_relaxation), which often quickens the search (at the cost of optimality).

A good simple heuristic for a grid is [manhattan distances](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry).

Comment: A* will give a small boost in (theoretical) performance, but will likely be slower than BFS as it requires the use of a heap ( making it O(n log n) in the number of nodes `n`.)

The real optimization for these real world applications is to do bidirectional search (meet in the middle), see https://efficientcodeblog.wordpress.com/2017/12/13/bidirectional-search-two-end-bfs/  for an explanation why it would be fast.